# Really need two passes in this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

suppose I want to perform an action on each word if a sentence contains >= 4 numbers. For example,

- This is a string contains 10, 23, 30, 50, 60.
- This is a string contains 10, and it also contains 23.

I need to take particular action on the first sentence above, since it contains more than 4 numbers. In the algorithm above I came up with, it needs two passes of the string list. Is there a more efficient algorithm for this task? For instance, one pass only? Thank you.

```
void process (List<String> sentence) {
    boolean has4AboveNum = false;
    if(containsMoreThan4Numbers(sentence)) {
        has4AboveNum = true;
}

for(String word : sentence) {
   if(has4AboveNum) {
      doSomething(word);   
  }
}   
}

boolean containsMoreThan4Numbers(List<String> sentence) {
int numCount = 0;
for(String word : sentence) {
  if(numCount>4){
     return true;
  }  
 if(isNumber(word)) {
      numCount++;
  }
   }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think doing only one pass will improve performance? I feel like the actual cost of additional cache misses might well be negligible compared to the computational work your algorithm performs on the array elements. Plus the separate loops might be much easier to vectorize. I think you're trying to optimize prematurely, without having measured the actual cost of your two passes

Comment: BTW the answer to your question depends entirely on what doSomething actually does and what the probability is that your input string has more than 4 numbers in it

Comment: doSomething is, for example, adding a label to the "word". Plus, the probability of input string having more than 4 numbers is low.

Comment: So maybe you can just undo doSomething if you notice there is too many numbers. Still I'm very sceptical about the alleged performance difference

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on one path by parsing the string, and creating in a one pass on the string a `List<String>` that contains only the numbers in the string, each element in the list is a distinct number found in the string.

Now, all you have to do is check `list.size()` - and make sure it is in the desired range.

```
List<String> getNumbers(List<String> sentence) {
   List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
   for(String word : sentence)  {
     if(isNumber(word)) res.add(word);
   }
   return res;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not quite clear to me! Not sure you are clear about my question either :)

Comment: @ling I suggested first filtering up the list of words, and get a list of ONLY numbers. Now, that you have list with only numbers, it is easy to know if you have at least 2 words (list.size() >=2), an at most 4 words (list.size() <= 4), without any additional pass.